# Add leading zero to axis label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, leading-zero

I would like to add a leading zero to my axis labels in ggplot2.

e.g.:

```
data("mtcars")
ggplot(mtcars) + 
 geom_point(aes(hp,cyl))
```

gives
[image]
However, I would like to add a leading zero to "cyl" so that I have "04,05,06,07,08" as labels.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sprintf("%02d", 4:8)` as labels.

Comment: or use `scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("0",x))`

Comment: Thank you very much @Jimbou, that did the trick!

Comment: Adding to @Jimbou's code, I will say that this is more generic: `scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) stringr::str_pad(x, width = 2, pad = "0"))`